# Nested JSON with existing Views in SQL Server - Declarative ORM SQLAlchemy Models

Tags: json, sql-server, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on creating an account dashboard and I would like to nest the account assets via JSON. I am using existing database views that I've created in SQL Server. I've been trying to figure out how to nest the JSON and I stumbled across flask-marshmallow where you establish a relationship between child and parent.

My question is, is it possible to append a foreign key to a SQL view in my sqlalchemy ORM Models so that I can establish a easy child/parent relationship? I would like to not have to create new SQL tables based off the views I created. One person could have multiple phones and I would like a phone field in my Accounts model that could reflect that (child/parent relationship). All examples I have seen online were based of "creating" a new table in sqlite and I am stumped.

```
class Accounts(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "TCSAccounts"
partyid = db.Column('PartyID', db.Integer)
active = db.Column('Active', db.String)
fullname = db.Column('FullName', db.String)
lastname = db.Column('LastName', db.String)
firstname = db.Column('FirstName', db.String)
informalname = db.Column('InformalName', db.String)
adlogin = db.Column('ADLogin', db.String, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column('EmailAddress', db.String)
manager = db.Column('Manager', db.String)
office = db.Column('Office', db.String)
costcenternum = db.Column('CostCenterNum', db.Integer)
costcenter = db.Column('CostCenter', db.String)
inactive_dt = db.Column('Inactive_DT', db.DateTime)
un_extension = db.Column('un_extension', db.String)
un_employeeid = db.Column('un_employeeid', db.String)
un_unitysearch = db.Column('un_phonesystem', db.String)
xo_name = db.Column('xo_name', db.String)
xo_phone = db.Column('xo_phone', db.String)
xo_email = db.Column('xo_email', db.String)
mo_adlogin = db.Column('mo_adlogin', db.String)
mo_sipuri = db.Column('mo_sipuri', db.String)
mo_username = db.Column('mo_username', db.String)

class Phones(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "PhoneAssets"
ph_dn = db.Column('dn', db.String)
ph_device = db.Column('device', db.String)
ph_description = db.Column('description', db.String)
ph_adlogin = db.Column('ADLogin', db.String)
in_key = db.Column('Key', db.String)
in_name = db.Column('Name', db.String)
in_assettag = db.Column('AssetTag', db.String)
in_status = db.Column('InsightStatus', db.String)
in_serial = db.Column('Serial', db.String)
in_description = db.Column('InsightDescription', db.String)
in_location = db.Column('Location', db.String)
in_costcenter = db.Column('CostCenter', db.String)
in_associatedperson = db.Column('AssociatedPerson', db.String)
in_adlogin = db.Column('InsightADLogin', db.String, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Like [these](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html)?

Comment: Yes a one to many relationship.

Comment: Elaborating may help myself, I get "invalid column name" if i declare a foreign key in class Phones and a relationship in class Accounts. Im assuming that i need to create a foreign key in my sql server tables but the problem is that they are views, not tables. I would like to know if there is a way to declare kind of like a local foreign key only visable in my sqlalchemy ORM models